# How can I fix streamlit groupby.transform error?

Tags: pandas, streamlit

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, 1, 3, np.nan, 3], 'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, 1, 3, np.nan, 3], 'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C']})


[ df1 ]
  name  value
0    A      1
1    A    NaN
2    B    NaN
3    B      2
4    B      3
5    B      1
6    C      3
7    C    NaN
8    C      3

[ df2 ]
  name  value
0    A      1
1    A    NaN
2    B    NaN
3    B      2
4    B      3
5    B      1
6    C      3
7    C    NaN

numeric_only_columns = df1.select_dtypes(exclude = ['object', 'datetime']).columns.to_list()

for i in numeric_only_columns:
    df1[i] = df1[i].fillna(df1.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean'))
    df2[i] = df2[i].fillna(df1.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean'))



df2[i] = df2[i].fillna(df1.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean')) working


my stremalit code

fill_na_columns = st.selectbox("select method?",('mean','min','max','median'))
                    groupby_columns = st.multiselect("Groupby columns select", train.columns.to_list(), default=train.columns.to_list()[0])

if fill_na_columns == 'mean':
   st.dataframe(train.groupby(groupby_columns).mean(numeric_only=True))
   numeric_only_columns = train.select_dtypes(exclude = ['object', 'datetime']).columns.to_list()


    for i in numeric_only_columns:
                            train[i] = train[i].fillna(train.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean'))
                            test[i] = test[i].fillna(train.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean'))
                            val[i] = val[i].fillna(train.groupby(groupby_columns)[i].transform('mean'))
```

Applied to train but not to test and val ..
Works fine on jupyter notebook but In streamlit, no values ​​are applied to test, val. why this happen?

Applied to train but not to test and val ..
Works fine on jupyter notebook but In streamlit, no values ​​are applied to test, val. why this happen?

Comment: Maybe you don't have the same columns? You should provide a reproducible streamlit example

Comment: With the same data, it works well in Jupyter notebook. (df1, df2 have same columns)